# How do I get different printer margins for different printers to stick?

Tags: windows-xp, printer, margins

I have a computer running Windows XP SP3 that has three printers installed.  I am printing from an in house web app in Internet Explorer.  Two printers can share the same margins, but the third one prints on sticky labels and requires radically different numbers to work correctly.

I've use the Page Setup option in Internet Explorer 8 to set the margins for the default printer, but when I change which printer is the default printer or print to a different printer besides the default one, it keeps the previous margins.

Is there a way to set the print margins for each printer so that they'll stick?  Or am I going to have to find out where the settings are saved in the registry and import them every time I want to use a different printer?